# How to remove treeview item based on value?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have this treeview with the main purpose to display open and closed windows in a building. For now the classes are "floor", which contains a list of rooms, "rooms" with a list of windows and the "roomwindow" class.

I want to display either open windows, closed windows or all windows by checking the corresponding radiobutton based on the "isOpen" boolean value of the roomwindow class.

Is there any way to temporarily hide or remove a "window" treeview item based on the boolean value of the room windows?
Or is the only possibility to iterate through the room window list and delete the windows?

The WindowCheck.xaml.cs

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.WindowCheck"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
   Title="WindowCheck" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name= "WindowCheckWindow">

<Grid Margin="104,113,60,0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" Reverse="False"/>
        <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverterReverse" Reverse="True"/>         
    </Grid.Resources>

    <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtn_open" Content="Open windows" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="99,-79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtn_closed" Content="Closed windows" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" Margin="256,-79,-30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rdbtn_all" Content="All windows" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-55,-79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Width="96"/>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FloorList, ElementName=WindowCheckWindow, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <!--RoomTemplate-->
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FloorId}"/>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding RoomWindowList}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RoomId}" />

                        <!--Window-->
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding WindowId}" >
                                    <TextBlock.Style>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rdbtn_closed}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property= "TextBlock.Visibility" Value="{Binding Path= IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rdbtn_open}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=IsOpen,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverterReverse}}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rdbtn_all}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding ="{ Binding IsOpen}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOpen}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow">
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle> 
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

The MainWindow.xaml.cs, where a test building is initialized:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private Floor floor;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBuilding();
    }

    public void InitializeBuilding()
    {
        floor = new Floor("FirstFloor");  

        List<RoomWindow> bathroomWindows = new List<RoomWindow>();
        bathroomWindows.Add(new RoomWindow("Bathroom window 1", false));
      //etc.

       List<RoomWindow> livingroomWindows = new List<RoomWindow>();
    livingroomWindows.Add(new RoomWindow("Livingroom window 1", false));
  //etc.

    Room livingRoom = new Room("Livingroom",livingroomWindows,floor);
    Room bathRoom = new Room("Bathroom",bathroomWindows,floor);

    floor.addRooms(livingRoom);
    floor.addRooms(bathRoom);
    }
   //...
```

Comment: Can you get by with just using a subset of the collection and assigning it to the `ItemsSource` property? E.g. You could select a subset of only open windows and assign it.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to bind TreeViewItem.IsVisible to IsOpen

Comment: @devhedgehog So you mean something like a BooleanToVisibilityConverter?

Comment: @Sarasa yes, visibility to bool

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom BooleanToVisibilityConverter, which hides the windows based on the boolean value of "isOpen". This seems to work fine with only one problem. Now if some of the window items are collapsed there is still a blank space where the item used to be.